# Problem with contact query and null string

Tags: android

EDIT: SOLVED IT :( AFTER SPENDING HOURS ON IT, IT WAS THE SIMPLEST OF SOLUTIONS. CORRECT CODE BELOW.

Ok. So I have the query working where I can look someone up by their phone number. What I want to do is if the phone number I look up doesn't exist, it just returns the phone number. Here's what I have so far:

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber)); 

Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);  

while(c.moveToNext()) {
    conname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }
    if (conname==null || conname.equals("") || conname.equals("null")) {
        conname = phoneNumber;
    }

if (messages.length > -1) {
    smsToast = conname + ":\n'" + messages[0].getMessageBody() + "'";
    Toast.makeText(context, smsToast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("Text Thing", conname + " ugh");
    Log.e("Text Thing", phoneNumber);
}
```

I tried everything to turn conname (the contacts name) back to the phoneNumber. It says conname = null if it doesn't return anything on the toast. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `c.moveToNext()` returns `false` the first time, then there's no chance of setting a null `conname` back to the phone number. You can use `c.moveToFirst()` to test whether the cursor is empty and assign the phone number to `conname` in that case.

Comment: Sorry... Still learning how queries work :/ How would I do this? Or what is the best resource/example for this? Thank you!

Comment: Wow... Just realize i had that if statement inside the while statement... If I put it outside of it (like I did in the edit I just did), will it work?

Comment: Seems like it to me. Any reason why you want to go through all cursor responses? Why not stop at the first non-null name? (In other words, change the loop to `while (c.moveToNext() && conname==null) { ...`

Comment: Not just more efficient, but probably more correct. Suppose there were two contacts with the same phone number, and the second had no display name. Your original code would set `conname` to the first contact's name, then set it to null. Then you'd set it back to the phone number. I'm guessing that you would rather have the first contact's name. By breaking out of the loop as soon as a name is found, you accomplish that.

Comment: Thank you. Forgot to accept your answer earlier. Better late than never.